# Realm no configuration change after removing PrimaryKey

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

Using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) I'm running into some migration issues, even though I shouldn't have any. All migration is disabled:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(dir)
    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
    .build();
```

However, I removed a `@PrimaryKey` of a class, which didn't appear to change the Realm significantly, resulting in the non-deletion of the Realm. Unaware this didn't delete the Realm, I got exceptions regarding duplicate `@PrimaryKey` values. Since I did not have any PK in my new code, it took quite some digging to find this out.

Is this by design? If so, what is the preferred solution? I am currently using version 0.90.1.

Comment: Nope that definitely sounds like a bug

Comment: Can you try with `1.2.0`? It sounds like an old bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this appeared to be a bug in the version I was using (`0.90.1`). Using version `1.2.0`, as [beeender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396606/beeender) mentioned, fixed the issue.